# How to uninstall onedrive in my laptop

Tags: windows, windows-8, onedrive

I recently purchased a Dell laptop running Windows 8. At the time of configuration of my latop I gave my outlook user details.

Now the problem is that the preloaded one drive is logged-in with my outlook credentials in which I have lots of personal data and my laptop is being shared amongst my friends.

Please help me to uninstall one drive from my laptop.  I am not able to find one drive in the control panel to uninstall it.

Comment: I've setup a brand new Windows machine. In the setup process, I explicitly selected to "Turn Off OneDrive". Setup finished. First thing I see on my desktop is OneDrive initializing and syncing. wtf!?? I feel like an idiot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This article [How to Completely Disable OneDrive](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/wiki/sdinstall-sduninstalling/how-to-completely-disable-onedrive/b97a8336-62e7-476c-872c-3286c0a01cf6) explains your various options.

---

For Windows 8, you can uninstall OneDrive as explained in the link:

> 1. Right-click the OneDrive icon in the notification area and then select "Settings"
> 2. Select the "Settings" tab and then select "Unlink OneDrive"
> 3. Click OK and then close the OneDrive window if it prompts you to connect to OneDrive again
> 4. Open Control Panel -> Programs and then uninstall the OneDrive program

---

For Windows 8.1, OneDrive is a built-in application, so you cannot uninstall it. In this case you have two options as explained in the link:

a) Disable the file synchronization while keeping OneDrive

> 1. Open the Charms bar, click "Settings", and then click "Change PC Settings"
> 2. Select "OneDrive" and then select "Sync Settings"
> 3. Disable the setting "Sync your settings on this PC"
> 4. Optional: Select the File Storage settings and then deselect the "Save documents to OneDrive by default" to stop programs from automatically saving to OneDrive
>
> You'll also have to make sure to not put any files into the OneDrive folder; once it's in that folder it will sync to OneDrive. You cannot remove the OneDrive while you still have your computer connected to your Microsoft account.

b) Unlink your Microsoft (Outlook) account from your Windows account

> 1. Open the Charms bar, click "Settings", and then click "Change PC Settings"
> 2. Select "Accounts" and then select "Disconnect" under your account name
>
> Your entire Microsoft account will be disconnected from your Windows account and OneDrive will not work on your machine.

Comment: how about windows 10?

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows 8.1, you cannot completely **remove** OneDrive. However, you can disable all of its syncing and effectively disable it. Simply open Control Panel, find the OneDrive section and disable all syncing.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows 8.1 YES YOU CAN completely remove OneDrive.

These are computers; if something was put on them then that same something can be taken off.

If you want to fully and COMPLETELY remove OneDrive/SkyDrive, all you have to do is search and download [Take Ownership](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-take-ownership-to-explorer-right-click-menu-in-vista/), extract it, and add that to your registry. It will create a context menu option.

Then open your task manager and go to processes. Scroll to Onedrive. When you find it, right click it and go to file location. You will see 3 or 4 SkyDrive files in your `system32` folder. Select them all and right click them, then choose *Take Ownership*. Then delete them and reboot your computer.

You're done for good. No more OneDrive.

Comment: I modified your method: From an Admin cmd prompt Run _takeown /f skydrive*_ from the windows\system32 directory. Then open the files properties in explorer, and set all users with full read/write privileges. Then delete them. I could not delete SkyDriveShell.dll, so that will have to be deleted after a reboot or from a Linux repair disc.

I noticed that there is still a Onedrive subsystem left behind at %windir%\FileManager\*, however I don't know if it is safe to remove.